# Link product variations to its own pages (e.g. blue hat to blue hat variation, etc.)

Tags: 7, commerce, views

I have a product display of two t-shirts variations, one is blue color and one is black. I also use it in Views Slideshow, to show it in front page.

The problem is that both variations link to the default one only. If default product display t-shirt is black, but also has a variation of blue, when clicked on blue t-shirt in homepage, it redirects you to the black version. How do I make it link all variations to it's own versions/pages? Is this even possible? Because when filtering variations on product display node, the page path is same and doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the following rewrite results: [path]?id=[product_id].